# Magento Toolbar not working with custom Sorting code

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I was trying to Sort product listing with created_at and group by Name, that why i added

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
                ->getSelect()->group('name');;
```

before

```
return $this->_productCollection;
```

in function `_getProductCollection()`

//app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/list.php

sorting is working fine but pagination and item quantity showing wrong.

[image]
It looks like only 1 products but i have much product here and i have not changed anything in toolbar page.

Answer (score 0):

The following url will be useful.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/51137/

Checkout the function

```
getSelectCountSql
```